# Can a process be stopped via a systemtap probe so gdb can be attached?

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, signals, systemtap

We have a multi-process application where debugging a specific child process is proving difficult. Due to messaging timeouts between the processes we don't have time to attach gdb to the target child, so I was wondering if I can stop a process via an systemtap probe?

A simple probe should, I think, be needed, eg.:

```
probe process("exeName").mark("STOP_HERE")
{
    force_sig(SIGSTOP, current);
}
```

Unfortunately, the above's not compiling ... any ideas?

---

I'm not a systemtap expert, so this isn't probably the best solution, but here's my crude solution for anyone interested:

```
#!/bin/stap -g

global gdbRunning = 0;

probe process(@1).mark(@2)
{
    raise(%{ SIGSTOP %});

    gdbCmd = sprintf("cgdb -- -q -ex 'thread find %d' %s %d", tid(), @1, pid());

    if (gdbRunning == 0)
    {
        gdbRunning = 1;
        printf("STOP PID %d TID %d [%s]\n", pid(), tid(), gdbCmd);
        system(gdbCmd);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("STOP PID %d TID %d\n", pid(), tid());
    }
}
```

Comment: I will recommend you start your process with single child process. It will be easier to start with single child instead of creating multiple then writing a handler to stop them ..

Comment: Rachit Jain; thanks for the suggestion, but that's not an option unfortunately - it would have made things much easier. Another alternative I may try out of interest is lldb, which starts up and can attach much much quicker than gdb can (but I'm sticking with fche's answer for the mo).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See man function::raise(3stap), new as of systemtap 2.3 (2013-07-25).

```
stap -g -e 'probe WHATEVER { raise(%{ SIGSTOP %}) }'
```

You need guru mode to let your script use this function.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much - this is exactly what I was after :)
I was sillilly trying to set task states per thread via set_task_state(...), but oddly enough that didn't work as it doesn't really tell the kernel what I'm attempting to do. No idea why I didn't think of kill(...) alternatives, i.e. raise(...)!! Thanks!

Comment: Doh! I'd read straight past raise in the docs! ... "function::raise — raise a signal in the current thread" :)